# "already defined" error within mdframed

Tags: counters, mdframed

Here is a custom theorem environment that utilizes mdframed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{ifthen}

%theorembox style
\mdfdefinestyle{theorembox}{%
    leftmargin=2em,
    rightmargin=2em,
    innertopmargin=8pt,
    innerbottommargin=8pt,
    roundcorner=8pt,
    backgroundcolor=gray!15
}

%theorem
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{%
    \newcounter{thm}
    \setcounter{thm}{1}
    \newsavebox{\thmargbox}
    \savebox{\thmargbox}{#1}
    \begin{list}{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}
    }       
        \item
        \begin{mdframed}[style=theorembox]
            {\large Theorem \arabic{thm}\quad\ifthenelse{\wd\thmargbox=0}{}{#1\par}}%
}{%     
        \end{mdframed}
    \end{list}
    \stepcounter{thm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[First Theorem] 
  If $a\sim b$, then $b\sim a$.
\end{theorem}

%\begin{theorem}[Second Theorem] 
%  If $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, then $a\sim c$.
%\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: custom theorem environment]

However, if the second theorem is applied, the following error is reported:

```
! LaTeX Error:  Command \c@thm already defined.
```

I think this may have more to do with my counter than mdframed, but any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: move `\newcounter{thm}` outside the environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That fixes the reported error, thank you.  But a second undisclosed `thmargbox already defined` error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move `\newcounter{thm}` and to replace `\setcounter{thm}{1}` with `\refstepcounter{thm}`, removing `\stepcounter{thm}` at the end.

But there are much better ways to do what you want with `tcolorbox` and the standard theorem environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtheoremstyle{largebreak}
  {}% use the default space above
  {}% use the default space below
  {\normalfont}% body font
  {}% indent (0pt)
  {\large}% header font
  {}% punctuation
  {\newline}% break after header
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{\quad #3}}% header spec

\theoremstyle{largebreak}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{
  colback=gray!15,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[First Theorem]
  If $a\sim b$, then $b\sim a$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Second Theorem]
  If $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, then $a\sim c$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}% no optional argument
$1+1=2$, no question.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can get a similar result with `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newtheoremstyle{largebreak}
  {}% use the default space above
  {}% use the default space below
  {\normalfont}% body font
  {}% indent (0pt)
  {\large}% header font
  {}% punctuation
  {\newline}% break after header
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{\quad #3}}% header spec

\theoremstyle{largebreak}
\newmdtheoremenv[
    leftmargin=2em,
    rightmargin=2em,
    innertopmargin=2pt,
    innerbottommargin=8pt,
    roundcorner=8pt,
    backgroundcolor=gray!15
]{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[First Theorem] 
  If $a\sim b$, then $b\sim a$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Second Theorem] 
  If $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, then $a\sim c$.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}% no optional argument
$1+1=2$, no question.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd like to use your `tcolorbox` solution, but it doesn't compile on my installation.  LaTeX reports 238 errors, the first of which is the undefined control sequence `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

Comment: Then you use probably a rather old tex system or didn't update properly.

Comment: @steven_nevets I added the `mdframed` code, but you should upgrade your TeX system.

Comment: @egreg I know you're not supposed to say thank you, but I can't thank you enough.  I'm happy to learn how to do this properly with `mdframed`, and even happier to learn about `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @steven_nevets You're welcome!